# todo.txt app missing the DropboxApiKey.h file

Tags: iphone, dropbox, dropbox-api

I downloaded todo.txt-touch-ios-master zip file from github.But when i open this applicaiton in xcode 4.4.DropboxApiKey.h file is not found.I got the erors like \

'<'command line'>':1:10: fatal error: 'DropboxApiKey.h' file not found

In file included from '<'built-in'>'
 project folder path'<'command line'>':1: 'DropboxApiKey.h' file not found in project folder path /'<'command line'>'
How can i get that file.I added manually That file.But it's not working.Again same errors came.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a project on GitHub called [todo.txt-touch-ios](https://github.com/ginatrapani/todo.txt-touch-ios), so I assume that's what you're looking at. If so, I see a file there called `sample-DropboxApiKey.h`. My guess would be that you should copy or rename that file to `DropboxApiKey.h` and plug in your own app key and secret.

You can obtain your own app key and secret by creating an app at the Dropbox app console: https://www.dropbox.com/developers/apps. Create a "core API" app, as it appears that's what this code uses. I can't quickly tell from reading the code whether the app needs to have "app folder" or "full Dropbox" permission, so you might try one and then the other.

See also https://github.com/ginatrapani/todo.txt-touch-ios/issues/163, which seems to confirm my guess.